# How to join with three rows from table one with second table in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

in laravel 5.6 i want to fetch data from database with join query in my case i want to join multiple tables such as employee, designation, booking, vehicles when i use join it shows following errors(SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'employees' (SQL: select * from `bookings` inner join `vehicles` on `bookings`.`vehicle_id` = `vehicles`.`vehicle_id` inner join `employees` on `bookings`.`driver_id` = `employees`.`id` inner join `employees` on `bookings`.`conductor_id` = `employees`.`id` inner join `employees` on `bookings`.`helper_id` = `employees`.`id` inner join `designations` on `employees`.`desg_id` = `designations`.`desc_id`)) i google it several times but i could not find any solutions how can i solve this problems your efforts will be appreciate in this case thanks in advance.

in my laravel model Booking

```
public function get_booking(){
        $booking = DB::table('bookings')
            ->join('vehicles', 'bookings.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.vehicle_id')
            ->join('employees', 'bookings.driver_id', '=', 'employees.id')
            ->join('employees', 'bookings.conductor_id', '=', 'employees.id')
            ->join('employees', 'bookings.helper_id', '=', 'employees.id')
            ->join('designations', 'employees.desg_id', '=','designations.desc_id')
            ->get();

        return $booking;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use table aliases and join `designations` three times:

```
->join('employees as e1', 'bookings.driver_id', '=', 'e1.id')
->join('employees as e2', 'bookings.conductor_id', '=', 'e2.id')
->join('employees as e3', 'bookings.helper_id', '=', 'e3.id')
->join('designations as d1', 'e1.desg_id', '=','d1.desc_id')    - 
->join('designations as d2', 'e2.desg_id', '=','d2.desc_id')
->join('designations as d3', 'e3.desg_id', '=','d3.desc_id')
```

You also have to use column aliases (depending on your required columns):

```
->get(['bookings.*', 'vehicles.*', 'e1.name as driver_name',
    'e2.name as conductor_name', 'e3.name as helper_name']);
```

Comment: when i use this it shows this error (Unknown column 'employees.desg_id' in 'on clause' ) not the best result which i want

Comment: Did you add aliases for all three `employees` joins?

Comment: plz any body help

Comment: Then you have to replace `employees.desg_id` with `e1.desg_id` (or `e2`/`e3`).

Comment: Do you want to join `designations` for all three `employees` occurrences?

Comment: i already added e1 but show only helper name not driver and conductor so what to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166704/discussion-between-shahid-hussain-and-jonas-staudenmeir).